# Can I use E2EE in combination with TLS when for example creating a chat application using Socket IO

Tags: ssl, encryption, websocket, socket.io

I am reading all about E2EE and TLS but its mostly about the differences between them and not about if and how they should or should not be used together. So I was wondering if these two should be used together when developing a chat application using SocketIO or websockets. I have used TLS before when creating client-server communication with SocketIO so I know how this works but how does this integrate with end-to-end-encryption? Are you supposed to replace TLS with E2EE or should you send e2ee encrypted chatmessages over a TLS connection?